# Luhn's Checksum Algorithm 's Solution in C

Tags: c

[here's the sample of the input and the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioy8s.png)

What's wrong with my code? The output on my Dev-C++ is alright, no problem, but when I submitted it to an online judge it turns out as wrong answer. I don't know what's the problem, and I prefer to not change most of them (because this code turns out from my difficult brain, I'm sorry). But any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
int T = 0, max = 0, X, sum = 0;
scanf ("%d", &T);
long long int N = 0;
//2891
for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
    sum = 0;
    scanf ("%lld", &N);
    int A = N;
    while (A / 10 != 0) {
        A = A / 10;
        max++;
    }
    int length = max;
    for (int j = length; j >= 0; j--) {
        int X = N % 10;     //1
        sum += X;
        int Xx = N / 10;    //289
        int Y = Xx % 10;    //9
        int Yy = Y * 2;     //18
        if (Yy > 9) {
            Yy -= 9;        //9
        }
        sum += Yy;
        N = Xx / 10;
    }       
    if (sum % 10 == 0) {
        printf ("PASS\n");  
    } else printf ("FAIL\n");       
}
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int Xx = N / 10;` possible loss in precision since `N` is `long long`. I mean `N / 10` may be too large for `int`. Also `long long` is way too small for numbers with 50 digits.

Comment: When handling things like money, phone-number or credit-card number, never use the built-in standard numerical types (like e.g. `int` or `float`), they simply can't handle it. For e.g. a credit-card number us an array of 16 integers, each element being a single digit from the credit-card number.

Comment: thanks for the advices, I changed most of the codes but with alike concepts. I just submitted some secs ago and got accepted! thank you so much!